# Is the Landau-Ramanujan constant irrational?

Tags: reference-request, nt.number-theory

Hi, [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki?search=List+of+numbers), in wikipedia, the Landau-Ramanujan constant appears under a list of suspected transcendentals. I could not find anywhere a statement or a proof of it's irrationality. So, my question is, is the constant irrational( since it's under a list of suspected transcendentals, is it right to assume that it is irrational?) And if it is, is there a proof available? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every number is a suspected transcendental, unless there's some compelling reason to believe it's algebraic. 

Answer (score 3):

This is not a definitive answer, just a few links.
[This link](http://myyn.org/m/article/index-of-important-irrational-constants/) of "important irrational constants" lists it as irrational, without a citation.
The *Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences* has quite a few references at [the page for Landau-Ramanujan](http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/index.html?q=0.7642236535892206629&language=english&go=Search), one or more of which may contain what you seek.